# Bootstrap 3 responsive design

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

When I use Bootstrap 3 for a responsive design site, it is ok if I use only one type of class, for example col-lg-* to my entire page, and then, using the media queries in CSS, to restyle the page for lower dimensions?

Comment: the question is ................?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap works **mobile-first** and so should you use it. You can add multiple classes to each column to make them look different on each size:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">X</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">X</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">X</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">X</div>
</div>
```

This will result in:

```
Mobile:
|             100%            |
|             100%            |
|             100%            |
|             100%            |

Tablet:
|     50%     | |     50%     |
|     50%     | |     50%     |

Desktop:
| 25% | | 25% | | 25% | | 25% |
```

When writing custom CSS, you should always start with the mobile version and then write media queries with `min-width` to target higher dimensions:

```
button { display: block; }

/* Tablet and higher */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    button { display: inline-block; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! One more question: in your answer you have included the classes for tablet and desktop. What about if in the mobile version I still want 50% - 50%, like in the tablet version, just with smaller fonts for example? How can I target the mobile version?

Comment: @CodersHub use `col-xs-6` class for mobile.

Comment: Thank you Forien! What about if I want to make some changes ONLY for the mobile version? For example, if I want a smaller font or different background (a change) when the screen size is mobile.

Comment: @Forien is right. And regarding the font size, you should set the base font size small (mobile-first) and make it bigger for tablet/desktop using media queries with ‘min-width‘